# how to do the same commands on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In windows I was flashing the iso to usb

and then I do this commands to convert it to mbr and format to fat32

```
0- cmd (run as adminstrator) 
1- diskpart
2- lis dis
3- sel dis (my usb) 
4- clean
5- convert mbr
6- create partition primary
7- active 
8- format fs=fat32 quick
9- assign
```

I tried a lot of commands but the usb is not working on my TV

it says wrong file system...so I want the same as windows commands does

Comment: Doesn't the TV offer an option to format a USB drive? If the TV handles the job, then the drive should work with the TV for sure.

Comment: TVs don’t generally have an option to format drives. Maybe Android TV does, but “old” smart TVs don’t.

Comment: @DanielB Not that smart then… :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to zero the first few megabytes of the flash drive, then do again what you did. This will make sure that nothing is left of the hack that is ISOHybrid.

On Windows, this isn’t possible out of the box. You can only do `clean all` in `diskpart`, but this will overwrite the drive entirely, which causes undue stress. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) probably does that though. It can also just format the drive without putting an ISO file on it.

On Linux, overwriting is easy. To do the first 8 megabytes, just do this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/your_drive bs=1M count=8
```

Or, if your `dd` is super old:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/your_drive bs=1048576 count=8
```

Just make sure you substitute the correct drive for `/dev/your_drive`, because there are no do-overs. Hit the wrong drive and you’ll have a very bad day. I suggest using the named symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id` or `/dev/disk/by-path` to reduce the likelihood of mistakes.

You can then either continue on Windows with the commands you already used or using any of the partition tools available on Linux. There’s lots of them. With `fdisk`, you’d do this:

```
# fdisk /dev/your_drive

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.38.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x1af82318.

Command (m for help): o
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xa07cbcfc.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p):

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1):
First sector (2048-2097151, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-2097151, default 2097151):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size XXXX MiB.

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code or alias (type L to list all): 0c
Changed type of partition 'Empty' to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.
```

Then use `mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/your_new_partition`.

Again, do not make mistakes in selecting the drive/partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put an iso onto a usb drive in Linux, the easiest way is with the dd command. DD will overwrite anything on the USB drive, so be careful to get the correct drive. The dd command must be run with root privileges, so either from a root login or with sudo. The command is:

dd if=[path to the iso file] of=/dev/[device name of the usb drive] bs=1M status=progress

Again, use CAUTION!!! Whatever drive you put in the 'of' device will be overwritten and all of its data destroyed.

Comment: If I understand correctly OP already did that, then undid it. Only the flash drive is now no longer working with the TV.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Glad you were able to fully explain what was necessary.